# MySQL 5.7 procedure call and output from SQL Server not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The script worked in MySQL 5.6, but not in 5.7.

Below is the information of the server and procedure I have.

- A_Server : SQL SERVER 2014 Enterprise.
- B_Server : mySQL 5.6
- C_Server : mySQL 5.7

**<< MySQL Procedure Source >>**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "P_TEST2"(out _result2 int)
BEGIN    
    SET _result2 = 2223;

END
```

- "P_TEST2" is created in both server B and server C.

**<< LinkedServer Info >>**

LK_B : A server to B

LK_C : A server to C

- MySQL ODBC Driver 8.0

**<< procedure call. Server A to Server B >>**

```
declare @result int;

exec ('CALL P_TEST2 (?);',@result output) AT LK_B;

select @result as  [@result] ;
```

> @result value : 2223

**<< procedure call. Server A to Server C >>**

```
declare @result int;

exec ('CALL P_TEST2 (?);',@result output) AT LK_C;

select @result as  [@result] ;
```

> @result value : null

I really need the output value.

Comment: When you created the Linked Server for Server C did you specify `RPC Out = true` in its options?

Comment: Yes. RPC out = true .
The settings of LinkedServer B and C differ only in IP.

Comment: Have you compared all of the values for Server B and Server C via `select * from sys.sysservers where srvname in ('LK_B', 'LK_C');`? Have you confirmed that exactly the same `P_TEST2` is deployed to Server C?

Comment: compared. all the same.
Linked server data source is ODBC data source administrator > system DSN > MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver

Comment: The mysql access account is the root account.

Comment: exec ('show tables') AT  LK_B; 
exec ('show tables') AT  LK_C;   

All works fine.
The only problem is the setting of the output value.